# Pre Highlighted Dates KivyMD DatePicker

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm looking to pass the KivyMD MDDatepicker a list of dates to be highlighted in a different color to mark that the user completed a task on those dates. I don't see anything in the documentation below for this. Is it possible or do I have to use a new calendar widget?

https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/pickers/index.html#kivymd.uix.picker.MDDatePicker.sel_day